# Термин о возможности

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, значение-слов, терминология

Как называется понятие, описывающее то, что результат чего-либо будет одинаковым независимо от того, произойдет ли действие в настоящий момент или позже до определенного дедлайна (после которого итог будет иным). 
Приближенные значения: потенциал, возможность, ресурс, объем пространства (но это всё не то).

Answer (score 1):

Не исключено, что для отыскания такого термина в виде существительного для "**того, результат чего**" потребуется образовать производные слова или словосочетания от более развитых терминов для "результата" (предопределённость, детерминированность, неизбежность, неотвратимость, инвариантность результата...), перенеся смыслы подходящего корня на "причину". В узких смыслах употребляются понятия "*порождаемость, генеративность*" (математика, машинные алгоритмы), *чреватость* тем или иным (в бытовом смысле). В широком смысле можно преобразовать *предопредел**ённ**ость* (результата) в *предопредел**ительн**ость* (способность предопределить, детерминировать результат), *детерминир**ованн**ость* - в *детерминир**ующ**ую способность*. В словарях такие существительные не приводятся, а в текстах соотв. понятия часто встречаются в форме прилагательных (**предопределяющий, детерминирующий**).